# Event delayed when in a loop

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, hook, mouse

I use the global mouse hooks from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) page in a project. I want the mouse to move a specified path when it is clicked, but interupted if I let go of the mouse button, but for some reason the HookManager_MouseUp won't fire until round about 175 loops in my for-loop (forloop is for moving the mouse). (That should be about 0.4 seconds). No matter how long I press the mousebutton it will only stop the loop after those 0.4 seconds. If I wait longer than that it will stop the loop immediately when I let go of the mousebutton.

```
    public void MoveMouse()
    {
        btm = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);
        for (int i = 0; i < BézierPointList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!run) { break; }
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point((int)BézierPointList[i].X(), (int)BézierPointList[i].Y());
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(btm);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), (int)BézierPointList[i].X(), (int)BézierPointList[i].Y(), 1, 1);
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
        }
        CreateGraphics().DrawImage(btm, 0, 0);
    }
```

(The graphics are for debugging).
Is there some way to update the events, or something else I can do to fix this? Thanks! (C#)

Edit:
My Form1.Designer.cs contains this code (among other) 
            `Gma.UserActivityMonitor.HookManager.MouseDown += HookManager_MouseDown;
            Gma.UserActivityMonitor.HookManager.MouseUp += HookManager_MouseUp;`
And the methods HookManager_MouseUp and HookManager_MouseDown enters MoveMouse() and brakes it. The delay happens before HookManager_MouseUp (HookManager_MouseUp breaks the loop pretty much instantaneosly).